# Which action does wp_update_user triggers?

Tags: functions, hooks, wpdb, actions, updates

I am working modifying an ecommerce plugin, and it makes uses of wp_update_user() function, and everytime the function runs another table (created by the plugin), gets updated too. The problem is that the updated data on that second table is incorrect, and I am having troubles finding the part of the code that does it.

**So I was wondering, does the wp_update_user( )  function triggers some "action" so I can search for that in all the files?** like those used in for example:

```
add_action('wp_logout', 'logout_handler');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_update_user()` is in `/wp-includes/user.php` lines 1401-1439.  It uses `wp_insert_user()` (same file, lines 1254-1380) to update the existing user or add a new one if the user doesn't exist.  That function is where the various filters and actions affecting user account info live, and shows everything you can do to the `$user` object.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is updated this action is called, with these parameters: 
`'profile_update', $user_id, $old_user_data );`

Here is the relevant code from `user.php` in `wp_insert_user()`

```
if ( $update ) {
    /**
     * Fires immediately after an existing user is updated.
     *
     * @since 2.0.0
     *
     * @param int     $user_id       User ID.
     * @param WP_User $old_user_data Object containing user's data prior to update.
     */
    do_action( 'profile_update', $user_id, $old_user_data );
} else {
    /**
     * Fires immediately after a new user is registered.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     *
     * @param int $user_id User ID.
     */
    do_action( 'user_register', $user_id );
}
```